# Problem on creating 1st database table on laravel

Tags: laravel-5.6

I can't create table on my laravel project. It show me the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error telling you that this user dosen't have right to manage your database. You need to check `.env` config and see that you provide correct database connection settings...

If yes, log in to your database and check if that user have all rights in that database without `manage`.

If no, change your credentials and try once again. If this will not work, write me a comment and I will try to help once more :)